# R create a matrix of occurence

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I'm trying to find a faster way to sum the occurrence of individuals in sessions, in order to calculate their level of relationship. Basically, I'd like to count for each two individuals how many times at least one of them was observed. I've looked into answers here including melt and acast but did not find a good way to use them. This is my inefficient code:

```
presence=array(0,c(8,10)) #  session by individual
counter=array(0,c(10,10))
# put some data into the array:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0     1


  for (a in 1:10){
    for (b in 1:10){
      for (c in 1:8) {
        if ((presence[c,a]>0)|(presence[c,b]>0)) counter[a,b]=counter[a,b]+1
        # calculate something using this counter for each two individuals a and b
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help.
Amiyaal

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem a little bit more, I have no idea what's going on here.  What does your raw data look like?  And where is it represented in this code?  If you want to calculate the co-occurrence of people in events from raw data then that's certainly possible, I would suggest looking at some of the igraph social network analysis libraries.

Comment: Your question makes no sense as stated.  You use the statement, "sum the occurrence of individuals in sessions over years" without defining any terms and the code you supplied is garbage.

Comment: the presence array stores which individuals were present in session c in year i. The inner for loop counts the number of times that at least one of them (a or b) was present during a year (i.e. summing all sessions). I Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Not more clear at all.  It's just 4.5 million zeros.  Seriously reconsider what your asking and how you're presenting the problem.  1. Use a smaller **representative** sample.  2. Make sure the code is runnable. (yours is not) 3. Explain your situation thoroughly.

Comment: I changed the code to be simpler and focused on my question.

Comment: I will happily vote to re-open this question if you can take this statement: "I'd like to count for each two individuals how many times at least one of them was observed" and re-express that as something that is remotely comprehensible.

Comment: This last statement explains what I want to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, still not perfectly clear, but I THINK that presence is now an adjacency matrix, where the columns represent users and the rows represent events, so `presence[i,j]` indicates that user i attended event j.

If I'm interpreting it correctly then counts seems to be the co-occurrence matrix, correct?  `count[i,j]` should record the number of events users i and j attended together?

If you look into the literature on 2-mode social network analysis, and specifically into affiliation networks, there is a direct calculation for this:

```
count = t(presence)%*%presence
```

Now I would check that with your own data to make sure it's accurate: just check a couple cells randomly in count and compare them to presence.

Also, as an aside, with these kind of matrices rows are traditionally users and events are columns.

EDIT: if instead you want count to be the number of events EITHER user attended (as opposed to the number of events they BOTH attended) then it's a union rather than an intersection.  So it would be the number of events user i attended + the number of events user j attended - the intersection

```
x = t(presence)%*%presence
numEvents = diag(x)
counts = matrix(rep(numEvents,dim(x)[1]),nrow=dim(x)[1],byrow=TRUE)+matrix(rep(numEvents,dim(x)[1]),nrow=dim(x)[1],byrow=FALSE)-x
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it should work

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, as it calculates CO-OCCURRENCE, while I want to count all cases where AT LEAST one of them was present.